# Mac os, external monitor blurry and low res

Tags: display, resolution

Today I was using my 4k monitor (which I've been using my with current laptop for a very long time and everything was fine). I stepped away from the computer for 5 minutes, when I got back, the monitor was low res and the text is fuzzy.

I went to the apple menu to try to change the resolution, but now the high resolution options are not available anymore!

What happened here?

I tried restarting the computer and it didn't work.

I have the 2020 macbook air with the m1 processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though a restart didn't work. A shutdown followed by power on did work. I wonder why.

Comment: How precisely does your display connect to your Mac?

Comment: through a dongle, there's an hdmi port on the dongle

Comment: Ok. So the display sends [EDID via HDMI and that tells the OS what resolutions the display supports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data). Sometimes you do have to power everything or rot tell the display not to auto sense inputs so it answers the Mac when asked what it supports…

Comment: @bmike now i happened again and what i describe didn't help...

Comment: If the built-in screen displays correctly, the dongle or the external screen or the cable between them may have an intermittent fault,